# expected value of minimum of sum random variable uniformly distributed variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3$...  random variables uniformly distributed over the interval [0,1].
Define $n(x)$ as $n(x)$= $\min$ $\{$$n$| $\sum_1^n$ $U_i>x$$\}$. I need to find $\Bbb E[n(x)]$
I tried to find $\Bbb E[n(x)]$ conditioning on the value of  $U_1$ than i use the fact
$\tag{2}\Bbb E \left[ n(x) | U_1=y\right] = \cases{1,& $y>x$\cr 1+\Bbb E(x-y),& $y\le x $}.$ but I'm struggling to build the integral, I don't know how to proceed any further than that. I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You meant $1+\Bbb E[n(x-y)]$, right?

Comment: You have the right idea conditioning on $U_1$. I suggest you set $$f(x)=\mathbb{E}\big(n(x)\big)$$ and use the total law of expectation to derive an equation involving $f$.

Comment: When the target  $x =1$, there is an elegant solution that the expected length of the stopped sum is  exactly $e \approx 2.718$. For integer $x >1$, the expected length  of the stopped sum is extremely well approximated by  $2 x + \frac23$. There are a number of approaches (most being limit or approximations) at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068112/what-is-the-expected-number-of-randomly-generated-numbers-in-the-range-a-b-re?noredirect=1&lq=1 ... that may give some comfort to this very simple form.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214399/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem on the right track.

Letting $g(x) = E[n(x)]$, applying the total law of expectation and using the fact that $f_U(u)=1 [0\le u \le 1]$ I get:

$$ g(x) =\begin{cases}
1 + \int_0^x g(u) du &0\le x\le1\\
1 + \int_{x-1}^x g(u) du & x >1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

This gives $g(x) = \exp(x)$ for $0\le x\le1$

In general, $g(x)$ can be expressed as a sum of piecewise differentiable functions in each interval $[k,k+1]$, $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k(x) $ where

$$g_k(x)= \exp(x-k) h_k(x-n) \quad [ k\le x < k+1] $$
and $h_k(\cdot)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$

The first values are $h_0(x)=1$, $h_1(x)=e-x$ , $h_2(x)=\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2}-e x+{{e}^{2}}- e$

[image]

For large $x$, $g(x) \approx 2x + \frac23$ (empirically)

Added: The functions $h_k(x)$ are produced by this recursion:

$$ h_k(x) = e \,h_{k-1}(1) - \int_0^x h_{k-1}(u) du $$

Comment: I don't know what function is $g(u)$, is a PDF of  a uniform distribution?

Comment: No, $g(\cdot)$ is defined in the first paragraph

Comment: Sorry for the number of comments, but I don't understanding how you find g(x)=$e^x$. What method you use to solve the equation system?

Comment: $g(x) = 1 + \int_0^x g(u) du$ is an integral equation, that can be transformed into an easy differential equation by differentiating in both sides.

Comment: How do you determine the functions $h_k(x)$? Perhaps is there a recurrence relation $h_k(x) = f(h_{k-1}(x))$ where the function $f$ is well defined?

Comment: @NN2 see the edited answer

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of notation, let's denote $U_0 =0$.
The probability of the event $\{n(x)=k \}$ for $k\in \mathbb{N^*}$ is
\begin{align}
P(n(x)=k) &= P(\{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}U_k<x\}\cap  \{\sum_{i=0}^{k}U_k \ge x \}) \\
&= P(\{S_k-U_k<x\}\cap  \{S_k \ge x \}) \\
\end{align}
with $S_k$ defined as $S_k=\sum_{i=0}^{k}U_k$.

We have $S_k$ follows the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution#Definition) with the density function $f(s;k)$. Hence
\begin{align}
P(n(x)=k) &= P(\{S_k-U_k<x\}\cap  \{S_k \ge x \}) \\
&= P(x\le S_k \le x +U_k ) \\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_{x}^{\min\{x+u,k\}} f(s;k)ds\right)du \\
\end{align}

And the expectation $E(n(x))$ is then calculated as

$$E(n(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\int_0^1  \int_{x}^{\min\{x+u,k\}} f(s;k)dsdu\right)$$

PS: I think the solution of leonbloy is better than mine.

Comment: Upvoting because I'd never heard it called the Irwin-Hall distribution and I learned something from you @NN2, thank you.